# Excel VBA to update TOC and Table of Tables

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble getting my excel macro to update my word document (opened from excel) to update the table of tables.  I have a table of contents and that gets updated, but the tables does not.  I have read that a table of tables is really a TOC, but it still will not update.  I currently have this:

```
wApp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).UpdatePageNumbers
wApp.ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(2).UpdatePageNumbers
```

(`wApp` was defined in another part of the code to open a word document)

I am only using page numbers because the titles of the tables never change.

Comment: I just tried it out (O365) and no issues.  Simple question, are you saving the document before closing?

Comment: The word doc is a template.  I save it as another file name when I do save it, otherwise it loses the bookmarks I need for pasting tables.  Not sure if it makes a difference but I am using Office Professional Plus 2016.